# Why is this Remix.run npx create-remix setup script getting 404 from GitHub?

Tags: github, npm, npx, remix.run

In OS X terminal, I try to create a remix.run project using the command

```
npx create-remix@latest
```

and at the point where the script attempts to create the app, It exits with this error and stack trace:

```
Creating your app…   Using the cloudflare-pages template from the remix-run/remix repo
⠹ Creating your app…Error:  There was a problem fetching the file from GitHub. The request responded with a 404 status. Please try again later.
    at downloadAndExtractTarball (/Users/ransom/.npm/_npx/5164864a48bff686/node_modules/@remix-run/dev/cli/create.js:284:11)
```

More information:

- Node and nvm versions are the latest
- I get the same problem specifying older versions like create-remix@1.3.1
- I have used this Mac previously and successfully to create Remix apps
- It doesn't matter which Remix template I try to use
- I tested the npx script on another mac, on the same wifi network, which had never run it before, and it didn't have any errors.
- from the problem Mac, I'm able to push and pull and clone GitHub repos from the command line.
- https://github-debug.com didn't show any problems with my connection
- I tried deleting the entire contents of `~/.npm` and also running `npx clear-npx-cache`

Answer (score 1):

Check to see if you have GITHUB_TOKEN defined somewhere. This can interfere with the Remix CLI fetching the templates.